# Using the same randomly generated array

Tags: java, arrays, random

I am creating an array with a size based on user input and the elements will be randomly generated (0-20). The problem I'm having is I don't know how to use the same array with the same randomly generated elements into different methods.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class RandomArrays { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of elements: ");
        int n = in.nextInt();

        array(n);
    };


    public static int[] array(int n) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int random = 0;
        int[] array = new int[n];

        System.out.print("Array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            random = r.nextInt(20);
            System.out.print(array[i] + random + " ");
        }
        evenElement(a);
    return array;
    };


    public static int[] evenElement(int[] a) {
        Random r = new Random();
        int random = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            random = r.nextInt(20);
            System.out.print(a[i] + random + " ");
        }
        return a;
    };


};
```

Yes, this is homework for me but it's keeping me from making any progress.

Comment: `array()` returns something. Assign it to a variable and you have something to reuse.

Comment: actually you should also put something into that array, otherwise it will remain empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run

```
array(n)
```

it returns an Array. So save it to a new variable like:

```
int[] myArray = array(n);
```

and the pass myArray to evenElement

Comment: I tried this but now it's giving me an array with different elements, I need the same array with the same elements as printed in the `array` method.

Answer (score 0):

Keep back the `int[]` that the method is returning

```
int[] myUsefulArray = array(n);
```

after that you can simply do:

```
System.out.print("Enter the number of elements: ");
int n = in.nextInt();
int[] myUsefulArray = array(n);
evenElement(myUsefulArray )
```

Comment: This is giving me an array with different elements now.